# .net core installation and nuget

Tags: nuget, .net-core

If I install .net core sdk does this also install nuget?

Cant seem to find anywhere that says yes. Looking to know as I am looking to do this on our build server

Looking at cli there is dotnet restore, dotnet nuget delete etc, so I am presuming yes.

If yes can I configure nuget in the same way as it is when I install nuget i.e. through this file location on windows:$env:APPDATA/nuget/NuGet.Config

Comment: Do you mean the NuGet client?

Comment: yes the client to allow restore of packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the .NET Core Sdk ("CLI") contains a distribution of NuGet.

This integrated distribution is similar to the NuGet integration of VS 2017.

As you already inferred, it powers `dotnet restore` and the implicit restore performed during builds. There are also additional NuGet commands available via the `dotnet nuget` verb.

However, this is not a version of `nuget.exe` and most prominently does not support restoring `packages.config` based projects and `dotnet nuget` only supports a subset of features that `nuget.exe` offers.

Also, it uses the user-wide NuGet.Config from `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` directory on windows and `~/.nuget/NuGet.Config` on non-windows systems.